# How to edit ur nickname continuously with discord py

Tags: python, python-requests, discord.py

Im setting up the last feature of my discord bot and having issue with updating the bots nickname using the task.loop

Ive tried various methods form talking with people and reading through the docs, the problem im having is you can only pass self as a param through task loop. Im sure this is an easier fix then im making it.

```
def get_current_price():
    threading.Timer(15.0, get_current_price).start()
    r = requests.get('https://www.bitmex.com/api/v1/instrument?symbol=XBT&columns=lastPrice&count=1&reverse=true')
    price1 = r.json()
    global price2
    price2 = str(price1[0]['lastPrice'])
```

```
@tasks.loop(seconds=15.0)
async def change_nick():
```

top section of the code is using requests to grap the information from the API and then selects the specific number I want from the params i sent. the bottom part is just bit of code that ik is right about the loop and shows the timer i have for it

I have attempted to use guild.me self.edit and others found in the docs but im not sure im implementing then and cannot find any examples to reverse engineer and learn from.

Answer (score 0):

In order to change a nickname in discord.py, you must first get a `Member` object, not to be confused with a `User` object. A `Member` objects refers to somebody while they're in a `Guild`, whereas a `User` object is just someone that exists on the platform as a whole, you can only change the `Member` objects nickname because it refers to them inside of the guild.

You can easily do this by doing

```
from discord.ext.commands import MemberConverter

guild = self.bot.get_guild(yourGuildIDHere) # Get the guild in question so you can actually get a member object

converter = MemberConverter()
member = await converter.convert(guild, yourid) # convert a userid to a member object reffering to the guild.

await member.edit(nick=nicknameHere)
```